# Resolving pytorch distributed execution printing multiple log statements for each process spawned?

Tags: multiprocessing, pytorch, distributed-computing, distributed

I am running pytorch distributed environment to train some models and in the same script I am also using logging to print status of the program. The problem is that with pytorch distributed since its spawning multiple processes I see my log statements being printed `n` times where `n` is the number of processes being spawned. Here's an example of it:

```
1.0, 0.05, 2.1823, 0.1703, 1.9799, 0.2352
1.0, 0.05, 2.1804, 0.1674, 1.9767, 0.2406
1.0, 0.05, 2.1814, 0.1697, 2.0053, 0.2154
2.0, 0.05, 2.1593, 0.1741, 2.0935, 0.192
2.0, 0.05, 2.1526, 0.1779, 2.1166, 0.1908
2.0, 0.05, 2.1562, 0.1812, 2.0868, 0.2076
3.0, 0.05, 1.9319, 0.2473, 1.8041, 0.2903
3.0, 0.05, 1.9386, 0.2413, 1.8037, 0.3017
3.0, 0.05, 1.9286, 0.2443, 1.815, 0.2939
4.0, 0.05, 1.7522, 0.3153, 1.828, 0.3131
4.0, 0.05, 1.7504, 0.3207, 1.7613, 0.3245
4.0, 0.05, 1.7522, 0.3223, 1.7841, 0.3209
5.0, 0.05, 1.5815, 0.3951, 1.5559, 0.4307
5.0, 0.05, 1.5767, 0.3939, 1.5326, 0.4205
5.0, 0.05, 1.588, 0.3909, 1.5882, 0.3995
```

Any ideas on how to avoid or resolve this issue? Thanks!

Comment: check current rank and only print if it's 0

Comment: I've thought of that but that requires editing all files where there's a logging.info statement and checking if rank is 0. I was wondering if there's a more elegant way of handling this?

Answer (score -2):

You can choose to use NVIDIA pytorch scripts, it's optimized, which means it runs fast and print log normally.
here is the link:
https://github.com/NVIDIA/DeepLearningExamples/tree/master/PyTorch